# Passing date to a Crystal Report via a .NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a fully working Crystal Report that accepts a start and end parameter. These parameters are used in a SQL Command object in the report. I'm trying to embed the report into an ASP.NET webpage and pass the parameters from input boxes. Unfortunately the report loads with the parameters that were lasted used on the .rpt file and the input boxes do nothing (neither does the button). I was hoping that the report would not be visible until the parameters are set & the button is pressed.

As I am using `<input type="date" />` I'm not 100% sure if it will work as I'm on .NET 4.0 & VS2010, which are both complaining about the input field (but allow the project to compile without any errors, just a warning). I have tried with text inputs though and had the same problem.

I have not found a lot of documentation that helps me with this so I may be missing something obvious. Please help!

See code below. Note that I am using the 'Classic H5BP' HTML5 boilerplate.

default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = true;
            BindReport();
        }

    }
    private void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConfigureCrystalReports();
    }


    private void ConfigureCrystalReports()
    {
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("Report/Report1.rpt"));
        crystalReport.Filename(Server.MapPath("Report/Report1.rpt"));

        crystalReport.SetParameterValue("Start", text.Start);
        crystalReport.SetParameterValue("End", date.End);

        CrystalReportViewer1.DisplayGroupTree = false;
        CrystalReportViewer1.HasCrystalLogo = false;
        CrystalReportViewer1.HasPrintButton = false;
        CrystalReportViewer1.HasExportButton = false;
        CrystalReportViewer1.HasToggleGroupTreeButton = false;
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport;
    }



}
```

default.aspx

```
<%@ Page language="C#" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"
    Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Report</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>            window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            yepnope({ 
                test: Modernizr.inputtypes.date,
                nope: {
                    'css': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/css/jquery-ui.min.css',
                    'js': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js'
                },
                callback: { // executed once files are loaded
                    'js': function () { $('input[type=text]').('input[name=Start]').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }); } // default HTML5 format
                }
            });
           </script>
        <div><b>Report</b></div>
        <div align="center">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            Enter Date from: <input type="text" id="Start" name="Start" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            Enter Date to: <input type="date" id="End" name="End" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input id="Submit" type="button" value="Refresh Report" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" /></div>
        <div>
               <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" 
                   AutoDataBind="True" 
                   EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False" 
                   EnableParameterPrompt="False"
                   GroupTreeImagesFolderUrl="" 
                   Height="940px" 
                   ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" 
                   ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh="True" 
                   ToolbarImagesFolderUrl="" 
                   ToolPanelWidth="200px" 
                   Width="1411px" />

               <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
                   <Report FileName="C:\Users\administrator.DEVELOPMENT\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Web\Report\Report1.rpt">
                   </Report>
               </CR:CrystalReportSource>
        </div>
        </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using `report.SetParameterValue()` and ensuring this was called upon the button submitting. I also made sure that the codebehind was referenced in my default.aspx - think this was stopping all of the code running.